# What does moment condition mean i.e. $E|X|<\infty$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, expectation, statistical-inference

I read authors use the notion of "moment condition" and equivalently stating it is $E|X|<\infty$. Some have used the notion of "regularity condition" and try to explain why it is reasonable to assume or impose moment conditions in large sample theory.

I have the following questions:

(0) What is the difference between $E|X|<\infty$ and $E(X)<\infty$?

(1) What does this moment condition mean?

(2) Why is it important to have this so-called "regularity" condition in asymptotic analysis? I understand to the extent that it is required in both the Strong and Weak Law of Large Numbers theorems.

(3) Why is it sometimes equivocated to be "regularity" condition, and does this relate to the regularity terms we hear from undergrad Calculus class?

(4) Where else is this used in statistical inference or other than asymptotic analysis? Perhaps the discussion of similar moment conditions in the generalized method of moments or maximum likelihood method?

Thanks!

Comment: A ways better to be specific about the "authors" and "some have ..." It helps us determine context.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, it is in the context of econometrics. Time series data like stocks or cross-section data involving phone call surveys about household income The context is we are adding these regularity conditions as we make the leap from classical linear regression model (Least Squares) in finite sample to large sample with IID random sample case.

Comment: That wasn't the context I wanted. "authors" is vague. "Some people day..." is vague. Be specific about the context, in the question, or we don't know if you are talking about the guy next to you at the bar or the guy who first defined the moment condition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews FUMIO HAYASHI "ECONOMETRICS" He is in Roppongi, Minatoku, TOKYO, Japan just so if you are curious.

Comment: $E(X)<\infty$ does not make sense in general. $X$ is a random variable, so it is a (measurable) mapping from a probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ to, e.g., $\mathbb R$. The expected value is defined as $E(X) = \int X(w)\,dP(\omega)$. So the value $E(X)$ exists if and only if $E(|X|) < \infty$. The $n$-th moment of $X$ is defined by $E(|X|^n) = \int |X(\omega)|^n\,dP(\omega)$. Hence, $E(|X|) < \infty$ means that the first moment of $X$ is finite.

Comment: The expectation may be defined in an extended sense taking values in $[-\infty,\infty]$. It seems indeed that some people use "$E(X)<\infty$" as a synonym of finiteness of expectation = the integrability of $X$ = $E|X|<\infty$. 

Personally, I don't like this too much, but this is just a matter of notation.